# widgets not updating direction according to Locale language change - FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm still new to flutter and I developed login screen using Bloc pattern with language drop down. I used Scoped_model for widgets rebuild. When I select a language the all app update to the new language but widgets not update the directions according to the selected language. Ex. Arabic should be RTL but it still display as LTR.   Here is what I did,

```
class AppModel extends Model{
  void rebuildWidgets (){
    notifyListeners();
  }
}


class GlobalTranslations{
  static Locale _locale;
  static Map<dynamic, dynamic> _localizedValues;
 ......
  get currentLanguage => _locale == null ? '' : _locale.languageCode;

  /// Returns the current Locale
 static get locale => _locale;
 Future<Null> setNewLanguage([String newLanguage]) async {
    String language = newLanguage;
    if (language == null){
      language = await preferences.getPrefferedLanguage();
    }

    // Set the locale
   if (language == ""){
     // language = "en";
     language = _defaultLanguage;
    }

    String country_code=   getCountryCode (language);
    _locale = Locale(language, country_code);


    // Load the language strings
    String jsonContent = await 
    rootBundle.loadString("locale/XXXXX_${_locale.languageCode}.json");
    _localizedValues = json.decode(jsonContent);

    //Clear the cache
    _cache = {};

    // If there is a callback to invoke to notify that a language has changed
    if (_onLocaleChangedCallback != null){
      _onLocaleChangedCallback();
    }
  return null;
  }
}


void main() async {
 runApp(ScopeModelWrapper());
}


class ScopeModelWrapper extends StatelessWidget{

  final AppModel model;

  const ScopeModelWrapper ({Key key, @required this.model}): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return ScopedModel<AppModel>(model: AppModel(), child: App());
  }

}





class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  TranslationsBloc translationsBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    translationsBloc = TranslationsBloc();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    translationsBloc?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<TranslationsBloc>(
      bloc: translationsBloc,
      child: StreamBuilder<String>(
        stream: translationsBloc.currentLanguage,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot)
    {


      return ScopedModelDescendant<AppModel>(builder: (context, child, model) {

        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          localizationsDelegates: [
            const GlobalTranslationsDelegate(),
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          ],



          supportedLocales: [
            Locale("en", "AU"),
            Locale("ar", "AE"),
.......
          ],

          home: new LoginPage(),
          );

        });
       },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then I wrapperd my language dropdown widget with model and onSelect method I called changeLanguage method and then widget rebuild method from model.

Note : Just for test I extend my GlobalTransaction class with Model and called notifyListeners(); just after language change. But still same problem.

Any suggestion would be appreciate.

Comment: How did you solve this? My locale property changed but the app not updated to new locale I'm using provider